# count by on window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have created this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/53cd9/3) which executes this query:

```
SELECT "emails".*
FROM (
    SELECT "emails".id, sender_contact_id, sender_user_id,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY "sender_contact_id" ORDER BY "sent_at" DESC) AS "contact_rnk",
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY "sender_user_id" ORDER BY "sent_at" DESC) AS "user_rnk"
    FROM "emails"
    WHERE ("folder" = 'INBOX')
) AS "e"
INNER JOIN "emails"
ON ("emails"."id" = "e"."id")
WHERE ((contact_rnk = 1 or user_rnk = 1) AND folder = 'INBOX')
ORDER BY sent_at DESC;
```

The point of the query is to return only 1 row for each contact or user that has sent an email.

What is missing from the query is a count of the emails that have been sent for each partitioned user or contact.

I could do multiple with queries and join at the end e.g.

```
with main as (
  select blbah, etc.
),
cnt_users as (
  select count(sender_user_id) inner join main etc.
),
cnt_contacts as (
  select count(sender_contact_id) inner join main etc.
)
select main.*, cntusers etc.
```

But is it possible to include the count in the first query without having to use `group by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows may be counted inside each partition without `GROUP BY`, the trick being to use the proper framing.

For instance, the query could be modified as:

```
SELECT "emails".*, e.*
FROM (
    SELECT "emails".id, sender_contact_id, sender_user_id,
    rank() OVER (w1) AS "contact_rnk",
    count(*) OVER (w1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS contact_count,
    rank() OVER (w2) AS "user_rnk",
    count(*) OVER (w2 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS user_count
    FROM "emails"
    INNER JOIN email_participants ep
    ON emails.id = ep.email_id
    WHERE (folder = 'INBOX') and user_id = 220
    WINDOW
    w1 as (PARTITION BY sender_contact_id ORDER BY sent_at DESC),
    w2 as (PARTITION BY sender_user_id ORDER BY sent_at DESC)
) AS e
INNER JOIN emails
ON (emails.id = e.id)
WHERE ((contact_rnk = 1 or user_rnk = 1) AND folder = 'INBOX')
ORDER BY sent_at DESC
```

Then `e.contact_count` and `e.user_count` should contain the message counts for respectively each different `sender_contact_id` and `sender_user_id`.

Comment: @dagda1: sorry, sqlfiddle was down at the time of writing. Now fixed (moved window clause into the subquery)